# How would I conduct an equivalence test in R from an lmer() model?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, equivalence

Lets say I have a null result, as in the following example:

```
library(lme4)
iris$Rand <- rnorm(150)

m <- lmer(Petal.Width ~ Rand + (1|Species), data = iris)
```

How would I conduct an equivalence test on `Rand`?

Edit: I've found a great resource [here](https://pedermisager.netlify.app/post/mixed_model_equivalence/). But I'm still a bit at a loss on how to decide on the smallest effect size of interest? Is there a way to do it based on the sd of the DV?